# $array["key"] = value; or array_merge(), which is the fastest way?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Which is the best (performance efficiency) way to create an array in multiple files?
This:

```
$arr = array();
$arr["key1"] = "val1";
$arr["key2"] = "val2";
include "arr_2.php";

arr_2.php:

$arr["key3"] = "val3";
$arr["key4"] = "val4";
```

Or this:

```
$arr = array("key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2");
include "arr_2.php";

arr_2.php:

$arr = array_merge($arr, array("key3"=>"val3", "key4"=>"val4"));
```

Comment: Is this really an issue?

Comment: This may not be an issue but surely is a one of the optimization technique. Many programmers still don't know the impact of array_merge.

Answer (score 4):

`ARRAY KEY => VALUE` is faster than `ARRAY_MERGE`.

`KEY VALUE` is a simple creation of `ARRAY ELEMENTS` similar to creating a simple variable and assigning a value to it.

`ARRAY_MERGE` will always take previous array and merge values all over again, which involves more processing.

You will notice significant performance impact when run in a loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why down vote? I have seen many programmers use array_merge instead of simple array assignment which impacts performance. Have personally optimized it in few codes in real life.